# Cumulative count when two values match pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, cumsum

I am trying to create a new `Column` that displays a `cumulative count` based off values in separate `columns`.

So for the code below, I'm trying to create two new columns based off `Cause` and `Answer` `Columns`. So for the values in `Column Answer`, if `In` is situated in `Column Cause` I want to provide a cumulative count in a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Cause' : ['In','','','In','','In','In'],
    'Answer' : ['Yes','No','Maybe','No','Yes','No','Yes'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
  Answer Cause
0    Yes    In
1     No      
2  Maybe      
3     No    In
4    Yes      
5     No    In
6    Yes    In
```

Intended Output:

```
  Answer Cause Count_No Count_Yes
0    Yes    In                  1
1     No                         
2  Maybe                         
3     No    In        1          
4    Yes                         
5     No    In        2          
6    Yes    In                  2
```

I have tried the following but get an error.

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['Answer'])['Cause'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without for loop : -)

```
s=df.loc[df.Cause=='In'].Answer.str.get_dummies()
pd.concat([df,s.cumsum().mask(s!=1,'')],axis=1).fillna('')
Out[62]: 
  Answer Cause No Yes
0    Yes    In      1
1     No             
2  Maybe             
3     No    In  1    
4    Yes             
5     No    In  2    
6    Yes    In      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way -

```
for val in ['Yes', 'No']:
    cond = df.Answer.eq(val) & df.Cause.eq('In')
    df.loc[cond, 'Count_' + val] = cond[cond].cumsum()

df
#  Cause Answer  Count_Yes  Count_No
#0    In    Yes        1.0       NaN
#1           No        NaN       NaN
#2        Maybe        NaN       NaN
#3    In     No        NaN       1.0
#4          Yes        NaN       NaN
#5    In     No        NaN       2.0
#6    In    Yes        2.0       NaN
```