# How to calculate count for keys when values and entries match in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a bit complex aggregation and pivoting (i think) which i don't know how to achieve.
I have something like:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'query':['A','test1: A','test2: A','test2: A','AB','test1: AB','test3: AB'],
                  'link':['url1','url1','url1','url1','url2','url3','url2']})
OUT:
       query   link
0          A   url1
1   test1: A   url1
2   test2: A   url1
3   test2: A   url1
4         AB   url2
5  test1: AB   url3
6  test3: AB  url2
```

And i need what's below. Aim of this table is to show count of urls which match query value. For example, "test1: A" has "url1" as “A”, hence, count 1; "test1:AB" is not matching "url2" as ‘AB’, hence 0 and so on.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'query': ['A','AB'],
                   'test1': [1,0],
                   'test2':[2,0],
                   'test3':[0,1]})
OUT:
  query  test1  test2  test3
0     A      1      2      0
1    AB      0      0      1
```

Basically, i just want to calculate count for keys when values and links match. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053678/cumulative-count-when-two-values-match-pandas), but really did not help

EDIT: changed link value so there is no similarity between link and query

Answer (score 0):

We will have to do some basic reshaping and string extracting to see if AB is equal to AB.

The main methods we can employ are `str.contains`, `str.extract` and `str.split`

```
s = df1['query'].str.split(':',expand=True).join(df1['link'])
s[1] = s[1].fillna(s[0])
s = s[s[0].str.contains('[^test\d+]')==False]
```

---

```
print(s)

       0    1   link
1  test1    A   urlA
2  test2    A   urlA
3  test2    A   urlA
5  test1   AB    url
6  test3   AB  urlAB
```

---

```
s['link'] = s['link'].str.extract('url(\w+)')

s['test'] = s[1].str.strip().eq(s['link']).astype(int)


pd.pivot_table(s,s['test'],s[1],s[0],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)

     test            
0   test1 test2 test3
1                    
 A    1.0   2.0   0.0
 AB   0.0   0.0   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! However, there is no necessarily string similarity between query and link.  Sorry for ambiguity. I just want count all url of the parent (A) which are contained in the child (test2: A).